# React-Native Redux unable to set state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I use Redux to set three Counters for my navigation bar. I can access the values in initial state. But I am unable to change the values. My Reducer looks like this:

```
const SET_FREUNDE = 'SET_FREUNDE';
const SET_CHATS = 'SET_CHATS';
const SET_VOTES = 'SET_VOTES';

export function setFreunde(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_FREUNDE,
    value,
  }
}

export function setChats(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_CHATS,
    value,
  }
}

export function setVotes(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_VOTES,
    value,
  }
}

const defaults =
  {
    countervotes: 2,
    counterchats: 1,
    counterfreunde: 1
  };


function counter(state=defaults, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FREUNDE:
      return {...state,counterfreunde: action.value}
      case SET_CHATS:
        return {...state,counterchats: action.value}
        case SET_VOTES:
          return {...state,countervotes: action.value}
    default:{
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default counter;
```

Now I want to set the counters on a other screen:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet,... } from "react-native";
...

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { setChats, setFreunde, setVotes } from '../redux/counter';

class ... extends React.Component<{}, State> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  ...


  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={() => setFreunde(2)}/>
          ...
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  setFreunde: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setFreunde(value))
  },
  setChats: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setChats(value))
  },
  setVotes: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setVotes(value))
  }
})

export default connect( null, mapDispatchToProps )(NavStack)
```

If I log the setFreunde(2) the console says the following:

> Object {   "type": "SET_FREUNDE",   "value": 2, }

However, the value does not change which I retrieve in my App.tsx as follows:

```
const counterfreunde = useSelector((state)=>state.counterfreunde);
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Do you have just the `counter` state? Does `counterfreunde` selector return the initial value or undefined?

Comment: The selector returns the initial state. I have the three counter states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: Not Dispatching Action

```
<Button onPress={() => setFreunde(2)}/>
```

This code right here is just calling the action creator `setFreunde`.  It does not `dispatch` it.

Your `mapDispatchToProps` function adds a prop `setFreunde` to your component which takes no arguments and dispatches the action with the value from `props.value`.  **You are not using this prop.**  You are just using the action creator.  You need to call the function from props:

```
<Button onPress={this.props.setFreunde} title="Set Freunde" />
```

That fixes the functionality.  You do need to add a lot of annotations if you are trying to use typescript here.  It's easier with function components!

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import React, { Dispatch } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, Button, Text } from "react-native";

const SET_FREUNDE = "SET_FREUNDE";
const SET_CHATS = "SET_CHATS";
const SET_VOTES = "SET_VOTES";

export function setFreunde(value: number) {
  return {
    type: SET_FREUNDE,
    value
  };
}

export function setChats(value: number) {
  return {
    type: SET_CHATS,
    value
  };
}

export function setVotes(value: number) {
  return {
    type: SET_VOTES,
    value
  };
}

const defaults = {
  countervotes: 2,
  counterchats: 1,
  counterfreunde: 1
};

type State = typeof defaults;

type Action = ReturnType<typeof setVotes | typeof setChats | typeof setFreunde>;

function counter(state: State = defaults, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FREUNDE:
      return { ...state, counterfreunde: action.value };
    case SET_CHATS:
      return { ...state, counterchats: action.value };
    case SET_VOTES:
      return { ...state, countervotes: action.value };
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>,
  ownProps: OwnProps
) => ({
  setFreunde: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps;
    dispatch(setFreunde(value));
  },
  setChats: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps;
    dispatch(setChats(value));
  },
  setVotes: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps;
    dispatch(setVotes(value));
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  freund: state.counterfreunde
});

interface OwnProps {
  value: number;
}

type Props = OwnProps &
  ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> &
  ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;

class NavStack extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Freunde Value: {this.props.freund}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.props.setFreunde} title="Set Freunde" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const Test = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavStack);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Test value={5} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapdispatchtoprops-spv3p?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: thanks for your help. What do I need to change so that I can use the whole thing in a class? I have made your changes, however this.props.setFriends does not work:
`TypeError: _this3.props.setFreunde is not a function. (In '_this3.props.setFreunde(2)', '_this3.props.setFreunde' is undefined)`